# Integrate social network login however authenticate using existing credentials

Tags: facebook

We are looking to integrate Facebook, Google, Twitter into an existing site.

Unlike most implementations, the user MUST be a customer prior being able to login with Facebook, Google, etc. The current database design is as follows;

`userid | username | password | customerno`

So the idea is if a user decides to login using Facebook, we need to validate that they are also an existing customer using their customer number which is alphanumeric. Once authenticated, they are no longer required to authenticate using their customer number. If they are not yet a customer, they will first need to create an account with us.

1. Do I need to design a new table for each provider? If so what should the design look like?
2. How do I authenticate a user who has logged in using Facebook with their existing customer number?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I authenticate a user who has logged in using Facebook with their existing customer number?

That depends on what criteria you have to recognize someone as a customer …

IMHO the best and easiest way to connect Facebook users to existing accounts on some other page is the email address. If you don’t have that, and see no other reliable way to identify someone as a customer with the data that Facebook can provide – then maybe you could just *ask* the user for their customer id on your site before connecting their Facebook account.

As for your database design – if you read the email address on every connect/login, then you could just look that up to find your user id. Otherwise, you could either add extra fields to your existing user table, where you save someone’s Facebook/Google/... user id. But if you want to use multiple services, maybe it’d be better to put this data into a second table like

```
userid | foreign_user_id | type
```

where type would be one of 'facebook', 'google' etc. to identify the login provider that foreign_user_id comes from.

Comment: The criteria is the customer number. Not all customers have provided us with their email address and the email address they may have provided us may differ to the one they are using with Facebook. The only information we have is their customer number. How would it work asking them for their account number before connecting via Facebook if we want to provide them the ability to use Facebook to login?

Comment: Just have a text field for them to fill in there customer number. You could have them fill in the customer number before login in, but I’d say the other way around would be better: Have them login, and see if you already have a record for their Facebook user id (or external user id in general, like I mentioned before) in your table. […]

Comment: [cont.] If not, ask them for their customer number in a second step, and if that checks out to be valid, add a new record to your user table. (If it doesn’t, just tell them “sorry, but this is not a valid customer number” or something, and maybe let them try again if they made a typo or send them to the location where they can get one, if that’s applicable in your use case.) This way, when they come back next time, they don’t have to give their customer number again, because it’s already in your database.